# How to save each edited row data of a table in Angular (version 2 onwards)

Tags: angularjs, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives, angular9

How to save each edited row data of a table in Angular (version 2 onwards), I am getting edited values as blank. Can Anyone provide me a sample html with ts file for edit and save each row data in Angular? I have the following code tried so far
Issue: 1> Trying to edit one row but all the rows become editable.
2> Multiselect box values with ngModel, getting selected values but again on selecting in row other row multiselections are happening.

Please help me out with a iterative dynamic table having edit option, 5 columns, 2 are textboxes/spans and 1 is a multiselect dropdown.

TS file:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  ngOnInit() {
  } 
  qnaForm : FormGroup
  model: Array<any>=[{ question: '', answer: '', channelName: [{value:"1",option:"Humana"},{value:"2",option:"MyHumana"},{value:"3",option:"Military"}],profileName:[{value:"1",option:"General"},{value:"2",option:"Medicare"},{value:"3",option:"Employer"}] }];
  enableEdit = false;
  enableEditIndex = null;
  isContenteditable = false;
  hideIfEdit: boolean = false;
  inputQuestion: string;
  //isEditable=true;  
  editField: string;
  public multipleSelectChannel:Array<any>=[]; 
  public channel:Array<any>=[{value:"1",option:"Humana"},{value:"2",option:"MyHumana"},{value:"3",option:"Military"}]; 
  public multipleSelectProfile:Array<any>;
  chName: Array<any>;
  proname: Array<any>; 
  questionList: Array<any> = [
    {question: 'What do the provider ratings listed on the Find a Doctor tool mean?', answer: '<p>Humanas Find a doctor</a>&nbsp;tool displays ratings for providers in certain specialties and in certain locations based on quality and cost-efficiency guidelines as part of the Care Highlight program.</p>', channelName: [{value:"1",option:"Humana"},{value:"2",option:"MyHumana"},{value:"3",option:"Military"}],profileName:[{value:"1",option:"General"},{value:"2",option:"Medicare"},{value:"3",option:"Employer"}] } 
  ];
  myValue: number;
  enableEditMethod(e: any, i: any) {
    this.hideIfEdit = true;
    this.enableEdit = true;
    this.enableEditIndex = i; 
    this.isContenteditable = true; 
    //this.isEditable=false;
    this.reset();
    console.log(this.model);

  }
  remove(id: any) {    
    this.questionList.splice(id, 1);
    this.reset();
  } 
  cancel() 
  {
    this.reset();
    console.log('CANCEL');
  }
  add(){   
     // var recordCount = this.questionList.length;
      this.questionList.push({ question: '', answer: '', channelName: [{value:"1",option:"Humana"},{value:"2",option:"MyHumana"},{value:"3",option:"Military"}],profileName:[{value:"1",option:"General"},{value:"2",option:"Medicare"},{value:"3",option:"Employer"}] } );      
      //this.model.push(this.questionList);
      console.log(this.questionList);
      console.log(this.questionList.length);
  } 
  changeValue(id: number, property: string, event: any) {
    this.editField = event.target.textContent;    
  } 
  updateList(id: number, property: string, event: any) {
    const editField = event.target.textContent;
    console.log(id, this.editField,property);
    this.model[0][0][property]=this.editField;  
    this.myValue=id;    
    console.log(this.model);   
    }
  save(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(this.inputQuestion);
    console.log(form.controls['question'].value);
    this.multipleSelectChannel = form.controls['channel'].value;    
    console.log("Selected Form multiselect values",this.multipleSelectChannel);
    //this.multipleSelectProfile = form.controls['profile'].value;


    let index=this.myValue;    
    //console.log(this.questionList.length);
    for(let i=0;i<this.questionList.length;i++)    {
      //console.log(i);
      //console.log(index);
      if(i == index)
      {
      this.questionList[i][i]=this.model[0][0];      
      console.log(this.questionList);      
      console.log('SAVED');
      this.reset();
      }
    }
    //console.log(id, question,answer);
    //this.questionList[id][question] = question
    //this.questionList[id][answer] = answer;    
    //this.questionList.forEach(question=>{console.log(question);});





  }

  onFormSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.multipleSelectChannel = form.controls['channel'].value;
    console.log("Form Submit",this.multipleSelectChannel);
/*for (let i=0; i < user.technologies.length; i++) {
   console.log("Technology Id: " + user.technologies[i].techId);
   console.log("Technology Name: " + user.technologies[i].techName);
} */
  }
  reset(){
    this.model=[];
    this.model.push([{ question: '', answer: '', channelName: [{value:"1",option:"Humana"},{value:"2",option:"MyHumana"},{value:"3",option:"Military"}],profileName:[{value:"1",option:"General"},{value:"2",option:"Medicare"},{value:"3",option:"Employer"}] }]);
  }
  trackByIndex(id: any,item: any) {
    //console.log(id);
    //return id;
  }
  getSelectedChannelValues(id: number, property: string, event: any)
  {

    //console.log(this.multipleSelectChannel.length);
   /* console.log("Selected id and value",id, property);
    console.log("Selected event",event);
    console.log("Selected Value",event.target.value);
    console.log("Selected Option",event.target.option);*/
  }
  getSelectedChannelOptionValues(index:number){
    this.multipleSelectChannel.push(this.model[0]['channelName'][index])
    //this.multipleSelectChannel.push(this.channel[index]);
    this.model[0]['channelName'].splice(index,1);
    console.log("Selected id and value",this.multipleSelectChannel);
    console.log("Selected Model array",this.model[0]['channelName']);

  }
}
```

CSS:

```
body {
    color: #404E67;
    background: #F5F7FA;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.table-wrapper {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.table-title {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.table-title h2 {
    margin: 6px 0 0;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.table-title .add-new {
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-shadow: none;
    min-width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    line-height: 13px;
}

.table-title .add-new i {
    margin-right: 4px;
}

table.table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table.table tr th,
table.table tr td {
    border-color: #e9e9e9;
}

table.table th i {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

table.table th:last-child {
    width: 100px;
}

table.table td a {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    min-width: 24px;
}

table.table td a.add {
    color: #27C46B;
}

table.table td a.edit {
    color: #FFC107;
}

table.table td a.delete {
    color: #E34724;
}

table.table td i {
    font-size: 19px;
}

table.table td a.add i {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
}

table.table .form-control {
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

table.table .form-control.error {
    border-color: #f50000;
}

th.select {
    width: 5%;
    text-align: center;
}

td.select {
    width: 5%;
    text-align: center;
}

th.question {
    width: 20%
}

th.answer {
    width: 60%
}

th.channel {
    width: 15%
}

th.action {
    width: 10%
}

select[multiple] {
    width: 7em;
}

form {
    height: 35px;
    top: 7px;
    left: 20px;
}

#searchbox {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: 30px;
}

#searchbutton {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.coveo-field-caption {
    color: #414042;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <div class="table-title">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8">
              <form>
                  <input type="text" id="searchbox" placeholder="I want to...">
                  <button id="searchbutton" class="material-icons">search</button>
              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">           
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info add-new" (click)="add()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <form #qnaForm="ngForm"> 
  <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th class="select"></th>
              <th class="question">Questions</th>
              <th class="answer">Answers</th>
              <th class="channel">Channel/Audience</th>
              <th class="action"></th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let question of questionList; let id = index;trackBy:trackByIndex">
               <td class="select">
                  <input type="checkbox" />
              </td>
              <td>                                  
               <span name="question" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'question', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'question', $event)" [attr.contenteditable]= "isContenteditable && enableEditIndex == id ? true : false" value="question.question" >{{question.question}}</span>
               <!--  <input name="question" [readonly]="isEditable" *ngIf="enableEditIndex == id" type="text" value="{{question.question}}"/>

                <span class="question" *ngIf="!hideIfEdit" [attr.contenteditable]= "isContenteditable && enableEditIndex == id ? true : false">{{question.question}}</span>
                <input type="text" multiple name="question" *ngIf="hideIfEdit" value="{{question.question}}"/>-->

                </td>
              <td>
                <span name="answer" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'answer', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'answer', $event)"  [attr.contenteditable]= "isContenteditable && enableEditIndex == id ? true : false">{{question.answer}}</span>            
                <!--<textarea name="answer" [readonly]="isEditable && enableEditIndex == id ? false : true" value="{{question.answer}}"></textarea>-->    
              </td>
              <td>
                <select multiple name="channel" ngModel>
                    <option *ngFor="let channel of question.channelName; let i=index" 
                    value="{{channel.value}}">{{channel.option}}</option>                         
                </select>   
               <h5>{{multipleSelectChannel | json}}</h5>
                  <select multiple name="profile" [(ngModel)] ="multipleSelectProfile">
                        <option *ngFor="let profile of question.profileName" value="{{profile.value}}">{{profile.option}}</option>                         
                      </select>
                      <h5>{{multipleSelectProfile}}</h5>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <a class="edit" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit" *ngIf="!enableEdit || enableEditIndex != id" (click)="enableEditMethod($event, id)"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
                  <button *ngIf="enableEdit && enableEditIndex == id" (click)="enableEdit=false;isContenteditable=false;hideIfEdit=false;cancel()" class="btn btn-info">Cancel</button>
                  <button *ngIf="enableEdit && enableEditIndex == id" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-info" (click)="save(qnaForm);enableEdit=false;isContenteditable=false;" type="submit">Save</button>                  
                  <a class="delete" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete" (click)="remove(id)" *ngIf="!enableEdit || enableEditIndex != id" (click)="enableEditMethod($event, id)"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
              </td>
          </tr>

      </tbody>
  </table>
</form> 
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, and [it's expected that users at least show research efforts they've made](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the code that you're having problems with, and what you've tried so far to fix it.

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut - Sorry I am new to stack overflow, now edited the questions and provided the html and TS file. Please provide me a solution. Thanks in advance